# How do I set sqlldr log file within control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a sqlldr (Oracle SQL Loader) control file (say myControlFile.ctl) and when run it all works OK. However, it writes a log to a file named myControlFile, I would prefer for it to be called myControlFile.log

I've read through the docs for sqlldr and I know I can set the logfile as a command line parameter, but I want to set it within the control file itself. This doesn't seem unreasonable given that I can set the bad and discard filenames this way.

What am I missing? I'm currently running this on Windows but it will ultimately be run on Unix.

Comment: The [default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_params.htm#sthref481) is the name of the control file with the extension `.log`. Are you sure Windows Explorer isn't just hiding the extension? (Tools->Folder Options->View->Hide extensions for known file types)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I saw (after my post) that sqlldr should be creating with a default .log extension but it doesn't appear to be. I'm using a DOS window for all of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you can specify the log file in the parameter file, specified with the PARFILE parameter on the command line.

Possibly the log file name has to be passed to the sql loader executable so that a failure in reading the control file or other fatal errors will always be logged.

Comment: Yes; if it can't create a log file [it terminates immediately](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10701/ldr_concepts.htm#i1004909).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree - though I think it is a bit rubbish that I can't set the logfile within the control file (if it can't read the control file etc I would have expected it to log to the screen). I'll accept this as the answer though!

Comment: Here is the reference for parfile [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_params.htm#SUTIL1036)  daily_report.par contains `USERID=scott
CONTROL=daily_report.ctl
ERRORS=9999
LOG=daily_report.log`
Run it as `sqlldr PARFILE=daily_report.par
Password: password`

Answer (score 2):

You specify where the sqlldr log file is written in the sqlldr call to control file, not in the control file itself.

Such as:
sqlldr user/password /folder/folder2/controlfile.ctl log=/folder/folder3/logfile.log